# Record the order that different options are chosen on Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

I am using Qualtrics for a survey and have been trying to find a way to record the order that different options are chosen for checkbox questions. For example, if there are 6 options in total for a checkbox question, and a participant clicks the 4th one then the 2nd one, I will be able to obtain a string "4-2".

In addition, I would also like to obtain a metric to see if an option is selected or unselected multiple times. I think this can be backed out by how many times an option is clicked. So for example, "4-2-4" will tell me that a person first selects option 4 then deselects it.

The closest code I can come up with is the following:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function (){

    this.questionclick = function(event,element){        
        //for a single answer multiple choice question, the element type will be radio
        if (element.type == 'checkbox')        
        {            
            var choiceNum = "${e://Field/choiceOrder}"+ "|" + element.id.split('~')[2];    
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('choiceOrder', choiceNum);
        }    
    }
});
```

However it only records the last click (choice).

Is there a way to change the code so that it can record all the clicks (choices)? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  On StackOverflow we help you with your code, we don't write it for you.  Please see the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! I've updated the question and added the previous code that I wrote for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${e://Field/choiceOrder} gets resolved on the server before sending the page to the browser. So the value will never change.  Try this instead:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function (){
    var choiceOrder = "${e://Field/choiceOrder}";
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){        
        //for a single answer multiple choice question, the element type will be radio
        if (element.type == 'checkbox')        
        {            
            choiceOrder = choiceOrder + "|" + element.id.split('~')[2];    
            Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('choiceOrder', choiceOrder);
        }    
    }
});
```